# spring-mongo Given DBObject must be a BasicDBObject

Tags: spring-data-mongodb

I have a odd error happening when I upgraded spring-data-mongo from 1.3.2.RELEASE to 1.5.2.RELEASE

I have an object that looks something like this:

```
@Document(collection = "foos")
public class Foo  {

    @Id
    private String id; 
    private GeoPoint[] tracks;

}

public class GeoPoint {

    GeoPointValue[] points;

}

public class GeoPointValue {

    @Field(value = "0")
    double lon;

    @Field(value = "1")
    double lat;

    @Field(value = "2")
    double value;

}
```

I have a test tat creates one of these objects, saves it, then reloads it. When it saves it looks like this:

```
{
    "_class" : "com.Foo",
    "_id" : ObjectId("53f6630df91f68368b17da91"),
    "tracks" : [ 
        {
            "points" : [ 
                [ 
                    0, 
                    0, 
                    999.9000244140625
                ], 
                [ 
                    1.8605, 
                    -7.6815, 
                    1
                ], 
                [ 
                    1.0885, 
                    -0.0001, 
                    1
                ]
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "points" : [ 
                [ 
                    -0.0001581075944187447, 
                    -0.003384031509668049, 
                    999.9000244140625
                ], 
                [ 
                    -0.0003763519887295627, 
                    -0.003578620265780311, 
                    1
                ], 
                [ 
                    -0.0006024558351500737, 
                    -0.003581886877337006, 
                    1
                ]
            ]
        }
    ],
    "version" : 0
}
```

but when it reloads I get the following exception which I have traced to the points array:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Given DBObject must be a BasicDBObject! Object of class [com.mongodb.BasicDBList] must be an instance of class com.mongodb.BasicDBObject
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isInstanceOf(Assert.java:337)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DBObjectAccessor.<init>(DBObjectAccessor.java:47)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.<init>(MappingMongoConverter.java:1046)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getParameterProvider(MappingMongoConverter.java:230)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:242)
```

Comment: Which version of spring-data-mongodb are you using? The snipplets above worked fine using latest `1.6.0.RC1`.

Comment: I am using 1.5.2.RELEASE. I can't easily go to 1.6.0 because it requires a upgrade to Spring 4 and I have some work there. Still I commented out all the troubles with Spring 4 just to see if it fixed this issue and it did not. I still have the error

Comment: I tried the `1.3.x` branch using both mongodb `2.4.10` and `2.6.4` as well as various driver versions but did not manage to reproduce the error you describe. The structure stored is `[ { }, { }, { } ]` like. Still when I insert a document by hand having a `[ [ ],[ ],[ ] ]` structure I can see the error. Would you mind opening a ticket for this one in [jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO) and attach the sample project/testcase showing the error that you have?

Comment: I have made an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1034 and a GitHub example at https://github.com/ryber/spring-data-issue. I guess I should have been clear that The struct is not created by Spring. It is made by another (non jova) system. The test just rams the exact struct into Mongo and then only reads it with the mappings.

Comment: https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-1119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `spring-data-mongodb`, `GeoPointValue` is a Map structure, so what it expects is `BasicDBObject` type - `BasicDBList` is for List structure, this is the reason for the exception, I think.

You can try to change values of @Field in `GeoPointValue` from **"0", "1", "2"** to **"a", "b", "c"**, maybe the exception will disappear.

I feel weird that `"points"` value is **[ [ ],[ ],[ ] ]**, it should be **[ { }, { }, { } ]**. You can revert the `mongo-java-driver` from 2.12.3 to 2.11.3, if the `points` value is **[ { }, { }, { } ]** after saving, then maybe the driver make some special treatment for **Number Key** but `spring-data-mongodb` hasn't caught it up yet.

Comment: You are correct on the base reason. The solution was to make a custom mapper. Also SpringWorks opened a issue to make the error more informative.

Answer (score 0):

I had The Same Problem
and I Solved it By Adding @DBRef to the field